# Get return elements of a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, introspection

Is there a way to introspect the variable names returned by a function?
Eg.

```
def foo():
    x = 10
    y = 20
    return x,y
```

I am looking for a way to see the return variable names `"x"` and `"y"`. Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to see `x, y` as an answer? What if there are more than 1 return statement in the function?

Comment: simply `return [x,y]`? Am I missing something?

Comment: This is a very difficult thing to do given functions can take many branches that can result in different return statements.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think OP wants, for a given function, the names of the variables returned and the count of variables returned.

Comment: That's impossible imo (and very unpythonic) unless you want to trust the function docstrings or something strange of that sort

Comment: @VeltzerDoron It is [perfectly possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48366253/8371915), won't comment on pythonic, without a context :)

Answer (score 4):

This is generally not possible. Consider the function:

```
def foo(x, y):
    if x < y:
        return x
    else:
        return x, y
```

Here we have a function that can conditionally return 1 value or 2 values (with different names).

If your function has type annotations then you can get the return type using [`inspect.getfullargspec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

```
def foo(x: int) -> int:
    return x + 2

inspect.getfullargspec(foo).annotations['return']
```

returns

```
int
```

i.e. the type that you specified the function would return.

**Note:** Because they are fixed, **it is possible** to get the names/default values of function parameters using that same method. I.e. `inspect.getfullargspec(foo).args` returns `['x']`.

Comment: I borrowed your "hard" example. I hope you don't mind (upvoted and attributed accordingly).

Comment: @user8371915 no worries.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of `ast` transformations should get you there. A naive implementation can be done like this:

```
import inspect
import ast 

def get_return_ids(f):
    def get_ids(elt):
        """Extract identifiers if present. If not return None"""
        if isinstance(elt, (ast.Tuple, )):
            # For tuple get id of each item if item is a Name
            return [x.id for x in elt.elts if isinstance(x, (ast.Name, ))]
        if isinstance(elt, (ast.Name, )):
            return [elt.id]

    # Get source and parse AST
    (tree, ) = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(f)).body

    # Find all return statements
    rs = [
        node for node in ast.walk(tree) if isinstance(node, (ast.Return, ))
    ]

    return [get_ids(r.value) for r in rs]
```

Example usage:

```
>>> get_return_ids(foo)
[['x', 'y']]
```

With more complex function (borrowed form [Alex's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1953800/alex) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48365074/8371915)):

```
>>> def bar(x, y):
...     if x < y:
...         return x
...     else:
...         return x, y
...     
>>> get_return_ids(bar)
[['x'], ['x', 'y']]
```

In its current form it supports only small subset of scenarios, but you can extend it, if you need.